# How to change column value with pandas .apply() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I stumbled upon an issue while trying to take data from a CSV file, assemble a key and then creating a new CSV file with only the necessary data.

Example data:

```
ID1       Data1   Data2  Price1 Color   Key          ID2       Data3   Price2
12345/6  950/000  Pd950   996    G    4/20017/6   4/20017/6   950/000   1108
12345/6  333/000  Pd333   402    G    4/20017/6   4/20017/6   333/000    501
12345/6  500/000  Pd500   550    G    4/20017/6   4/20017/6   500/000    577
12345/6  950/000  PT950   690    Pt   4/20017/6   4/20017/6   950/000    779
12345/6  600/000  Pt600   424    Pt   4/20017/6   4/20017/6   600/000    482
```

My code:

```py
file_original = pd.read_csv(path_to_file, sep=";")

def getNum(itemPair):

    # Uses data to construct the output
    # Returns a string e.g. "4-12345-6_12345-6_XX-333"


def processItems(row):
    
    first_nr = row["ID1"].replace("/", "-")
    second_nr = row["ID2"].replace("/", "-")

    color = str(row["Color"]).lower()
    alloy = row["Data2"]

    Price1 = row["Price1"]
    Price2 = row["Price2"]

    alloys = []

    '''
    Performs a RegEx search on the alloy information. The pattern checks for
    two alloy data sets within one string.
    If result is none, there is only one data set and the next RegEx pattern is used.
    '''
    regEx = re.search(r"(\w{0,2}\d{3}).*?(\w{0,2}\d{3})", legierung)
    if regEx:
        if regEx.group(1):
            alloys.append(regEx.group(1))
        if regEx.group(2):
            alloys.append(regEx.group(2))
    else:
        regEx = re.search(r"(\d{3})", legierung)
        if regEx.group(1):
            alloys.append(regEx.group(1))


    alloys = sorted(alloys, key=sortOrderAlloy)

    # Strips away any letters from the very first alloy entry
    if len(alloys[0]) > 3:
        alloys[0] = alloys[0][2:]


    colors = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(color):
        if color[i] == "p" and (i < (len(color) - 1) and (color[i + 1] == "t" or color[i + 1] == "d")):
            # If the current letter is "p" and the next letter is "t" or "d" consider them one color
            result = color[i] + color[i + 1]
            i += 1

            if result not in colors:
                # If the color isn't yet part of the list, append it
                colors.append(result)

        else:
            if color[i] not in colors:
                # If the color isn't yet part of the list, append it
                colors += color[i]
        i += 1


    colors = sorted(colors, key=sortOrderColor)


    # Check if there are more colors than alloys which means there are multiple colors per alloy
    if len(colors) > len(alloys):
        # If there is no color starting with "p", the alloy can be applied to every color
        if ("pt" not in colors) and ("pd" not in colors):
            # Counter variable for while loop
            c = len(alloys)

            while c < len(colors):
                alloys.append(alloys[0])
                c = len(alloys)
        
        else:
            # The amount of missing alloys for while loop
            count_diff = len(colors) - len(alloys)
            
            while count_diff != 0:
                alloys.insert(0, alloys[0])
                count_diff -= 1


    materials = []

    # Count variable for while loop
    i = 0

    while i < len(colors):
        materials.append(getMaterial(colors[i]))
        i += 1

    # Do some stuff to get the necessary data while assigning the following variables:
    # first_nr, second_nr, materials, alloys, price1, price2

    row["idNum"] = getNum(first_nr, second_nr, materials, alloys, price1, price2)

    row["price"] = (price1 + price2)

file_original["idNum"] = ""
file_original["price"] = 0

file_original.apply(processItems, axis=1)

file_processed = file_original[["idNum", "price"]]

file_processed.to_csv(path_output, sep=";", index=False, encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

The intended result would be a CSV file with just two columns "idNum" and "price" and the columns are limited as intended, however the rows all end up with the empty data I use to create these two new columns, so an empty string and the number 0.

After searching through Google I discovered that using .apply() does not allow you to directly change the data, instead it needs to be reassigned but when I change the respective line, I get an error.

```py
# Old line
file_original.apply(processItems, axis=1)

# New line
file_original = file_original.apply(processItems, axis=1)
```

The error reads as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prepareImport.py", line 278, in 
    file_processed = file_original[["idNum", "price"]]
  File "C:\Users\MY-USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 910, in __getitem__
    return self._get_with(key)
  File "C:\Users\MY-USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 958, in _get_with
    return self.loc[key]
  File "C:\Users\MY-USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1768, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\MY-USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1954, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\MY-USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1595, in _getitem_iterable
    keyarr, indexer = self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis, raise_missing=False)
  File "C:\Users\MY-USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1552, in _get_listlike_indexer
    self._validate_read_indexer(
  File "C:\Users\MY-USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1640, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['idNum', 'price'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

```py
Line 278 => file_processed = file_original[["idNum", "price"]]
```

As far as I can tell the dataframe somehow looses the two columns I add before reassigning it.
So I decided to print it to the console rather than trying to extract two columns, the result shows that apparently the dataframe was transformed to a Series, so it has just one column filled with "None" of the datatype "object" although it keeps the full length of 10550.

I found a few other possible solutions to my original issue but they usually addressed an error the user made. Of course I checked my code for similar errors but couldn't find any myself so I hope someone can help me out with this.

Thank you very much in advance! If I forgot to provide any kind of crucial information please let me know so I can add it.

Best regards
Eisman333

Edit:
Expected output:

```
idNum                              price
4-12345-6_12345-6_XX-333            250
4-12345-6_12345-6_XX-585_YY-950    2130
4-12345-6_12345-6_XX-333_ZZ-500    1560
```

Comment: It seems that you are utilizing the .apply method on the entire dataframe with axis= 1.  This will result in an output of a Series.  Don't you want to utilize the .apply method on a specific columns of the dataframe?

Comment: Can you include a short example of the file_original dataframe and a sample of how you'd like the output dataframe to look like?

Comment: @itprorh66 thank you for the note, I wasn't aware that using .apply with axis=1 would result in a series. I used that method so that I can work on the data on a row based level, using `row["data2"]` and similar to get the data I need and do some extensive work with it so that I can then generate `idNum` which is the relevant key I need to continue processing the data.
The example data I included at the top of the question is an example of the `file_original` dataframe, as for the expected output I added it to the question now.

Comment: @itprorh66 is there a different function that allows me to go through each row individually without returning a Series and instead allowing changes to the original dataframe? I checked out a few but couldn't find one like that.

Comment: There are several functions depending on what you want to accomplish.  Check out df.iloc or df.loc as two possible functions.  If you gave an example of the manipulation you want to accomplish, it would be easier to steer you in the right direction.

Comment: For example if you want to sum the price1 column and the price2 column to form a total price column you could do:  ``` df['Total Price'] = df.loc[lambda row: row.price1 + row.price2] ```

Comment: @itprorh66 thank you so much for the information, I will check out those two functions and see if I can use those for my purposes. Although unfortunately what I need to do is rather complicated, or at least it is complicated in the way I handled it, so I am unsure if those will work. For convenience I updated my question to contain practically everything that gets done in the `processItems` function in my code, any tips are definitely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough of your logic/program for me to duplicate all the aspects of your processItems function, but I would suggest you think about separating out the individual column updates.  You could implement something along the lines of the following where this method is called with the original dataframe:

```
def groom_data(idf):
    idf['ID1'] = idf.apply(lambda row: row.ID1.replace("/", '-'), axis= 1)
    idf['ID2'] = idf.apply(lambda row: row.ID2.replace("/", '-'), axis= 1)
    idf['Color'] = idf.apply(lambda row: row.Color.lower(), axis= 1)
    idf['Alloys'] = idf.apply(lambda row: process_alloys(row), axis= 1)
    idf['Materials'] = idf.apply(lambda row: process_items(row), axis= 1)
    idf['IdNum']= idf.apply(lambda row: getNum(row.ID1, row.ID2, row.Materials, row.Alloys, row.Price1, row.Price2))
    idf['Total_Price'] = idf.apply(lambda row: row.Price1 + row.Price2)
    return idf
```

This would require to separate the logic for identifying the alloys and materials into two passes, I suggest that, since you need to access both materials and alloys when generating the IdNum column later. Once you have all the data in the original dataframe, you can then  create a new output frame containing just the information you need for the final result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that approach certainly looks promising! However there are a few points I'd like to clarify to make sure I understood it correctly. So with this way I would basically create columns which then contain the data I need for the `getNum` function rather than using variables as I did before? Though for the alloys and materials, I assume the respective functions (e.g. `process-alloys`) would need to return the final result rather than trying to edit the values within the function itself?
And I assume I would call it like `new_frame = groom_data(file_original)`

Comment: Yes, the idea behind process_alloys would be to define a function that evaluates the contents of the fields within a row and returns a alloy representation for the row as either a numeric or string value.  The ['Materials'] column would then utilize the contents of the row fields to determine the materials field contents.

Comment: excuse the delay, unfortunately I was quite busy and couldn't try out your method until today. I tried out your `groom_data` function but when I tried to print the result to check, I got an error. `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'ID1'` though the strange thing is, this error relates to the line `df['idNum'] = ...` but earlier in line `df['ID1'] = ...` there is no error, even though there is also a `row.ID1` section. 
Clearly I must be overlooking something but I can't figure out what unfortunately

Comment: It worked for me?  Review your code to ensure each apply statement includes the axis= 1 parameter, also in my code I defined the column as IdNum not as you have shown as idNum

Comment: Indeed there was an error in regards to the `axis= 1` parameter. Since your example had this parameter missing for the last two lines, I figured that was on purpose and copied it like that. I now fixed it and added a few more lines to the function to make my life easier and now it works like a charm and produces the expected result, even with my column name starting with a lowercase letter! Thank you very much for all your help!